# Call transactional method Play Java JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have 2 database one is mysql and other is postgree.
I tried to get postgree data from mysql transactional method.

```
@Transactional(value = "pg")
    public List<String> getSubordinate(){
        Query q1 = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select vrs.subordinate_number, vrs.superior_number\n" +
                "from view_reporting_structure vrs\n" +
                "where vrs.superior_number = :personel_number");
        q1.setParameter("personel_number","524261");
        List<String> me = q1.getResultList();
        return me;
    }
}
```

from another method

```
@Transactional
public Result getOpenRequestList(){
    Subordinate subordinate = new Subordinate();
    List<String> subordinateData = subordinate.getSubordinate();
    ....
}
```

i got error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'db_hcm.view_reporting_structure' doesn't exist
```

so my Postgre method recognized as mySQL transaction which is the view not exist in mySQL database. how do I get data from different presistence unit with 1 method?

Comment: No idea what you are saying. an EntityManagerFactory is for a single database. So decide which it is ... MySQL or PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

I never did it (different databases), but I guess the following may work.

For example, you have the following data source definition in application.conf:

```
# MySql
db.mysql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
... the rest of setting for db.mysql

# H2
db.postgre.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
... the rest of setting for db.postgre
```

Instead of using @Transactional annotation, manage a transaction explicitly and use JPA withTransaction API:

```
private static final String MYSQL_DB = "mysql";
private static final String POSTGRE_DB = "postgre";

public List<String> getSubordinate() {
    JPA.withTransaction(MYSQL_DB, true/* this is read-only flag*/,
    () -> {
        Query q1 = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select vrs.subordinate_number, vrs.superior_number\n" +
            "from view_reporting_structure vrs\n" +
            "where vrs.superior_number = :personel_number");
        q1.setParameter("personel_number","524261");
        List<String> me = q1.getResultList();
        return me;
    }
}

public Result getOpenRequestList(){
    JPA.withTransaction(POSTGRE_DB, true/* this is read-only flag*/,
    () -> {
        Subordinate subordinate = new Subordinate();
        List<String> subordinateData = subordinate.getSubordinate();
        ....
    }
}
```

Note: I prefer always use withTransaction, since it allows better control of unhappy flow. You should wrap the call  with try-catch. If JPA throws a run-time exception on commit, you can do proper error handling. In case of using @Transactional annotation, commit takes place after controller have finished and you cannot handle the error.